# Spring Protoype Scope List

Tags: java, spring

I have a question about the `prototype` scope of spring.

At the moment i try to implement a wizard in a spring application.

In the wizard controller i have something like

**WizardAbstract Class**

```
private List<WizardStep> _steps;
private WizardStep _activeStep;
private int _activeIndex;

public previous(){
    if(hasPrevious()){   
        _activeStep = _steps.get(_activeIndex);
    }
}
```

A step in the wizard is for example an implementation like this

**WizardNameStep Class**

```
@Named
@Scope(value="prototype"}
public WizardNameStep implements WizardStep {

    private String _name;

    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return _name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name){
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

My Problem is, when i type a value for the name in the wizard and go to the next step, everything is fine. If I go back now  to the previous step, my value is lost. Does the get on the list, creates a new `prototype` bean?

How can i solve my problem with the scopes? I don't want statless steps, but need to call some spring-services within the steps.

**EDIT**

My configuration class for the wizard includes the autowiring of the step

```
@Named(value = "profileEditorWizardController")
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class ProfileEditorWizardControllerImpl extends WizardControllerAbstract<ProfileEditorWizardResult> implements ProfileEditorWizardController {

   @Inject
   private WizardNameStep _wizardNameStep;
```

Comment: Where are you autowiring the `WizardNameStep`? Calling `_steps.get()` won't do any "magic". It's just a regular method call.

Comment: @Kayaman updated the question with the inject of the step